# Undefined Reference to f_opendir

Tags: stm32, sd-card, fatfs

I'm using elm chan's FATFS file system to read from sd card on an STM32.

I'm getting an undefined reference to `f_opendir`, `f_readdir`, and `f_closedir`; however, I can use other things like `f_mount`, `f_open`, `f_read` and `f_write` just fine.

All these functions are in the same `.h` file and if I open a declaration of any of them, it takes me straight to where they were defined. So, why does it give me undefined reference?

Comment: functions are not in the .h files. You need also to have C files with the function definitions

Answer (score 0):

looks like You need to lower the minimization level in the library options. FF_FS_MINIMIZE Macro is responsible for that. Basically You can remove some functions to lower the memory space used by the library. More info can be found here: http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/config.html#fs_minimize   Good luck with Your project!